# how to call variant arguments method with unpack

Tags: lua

I am trying to run a redis lua mock project to test my redis lua code. but obviously, there are bugs in the redis-mock project.

When I call `redis.call('hget', 'foo', 'bar')` in my test code, the redis mock throw an assert error at [hash.lua#22](https://github.com/Redsmin/redis-lua-unit/blob/547985409df64a69f2427672d7f71fdf0f5d9110/src/commands/hash.lua#L22) which is call from [RedisLua.lua#20](https://github.com/Redsmin/redis-lua-unit/blob/547985409df64a69f2427672d7f71fdf0f5d9110/src/RedisLua.lua#L20)

```
-- RedisLua.lua
local call = function(self)
  return (function(cmd, ...)
    cmd = string.lower(cmd)

    local arg = {...}

    local ret = self.db[cmd](self.db, unpack(arg)) -- line 20

    if self.RedisLua_VERBOSE then
      print(cmd .. "( " .. table.concat(arg, " ") .. " ) === ".. tostring(ret))
    end

    return ret
  end)
end


-- hash.lua
function RedisDb:hget(self,k,k2)
    assert((type(k2) == "string")) -- # line 22
    local x = RedisDb.xgetr(self,k,"hash")
    return x[k2]
end
```

After trace, I found, the `self` is `'foo'`, the `k` is `'bar'` and the `k2` is actually `nil`, How can I fix this bug, the `k` should be `foo`, and the `k2` should be `'bar'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call `redis:call('hget', 'foo', 'bar')` or equivalently `redis.call(redis,'hget','foo','bar')`, rather than `redis.call('hget', 'foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: No need for thinking there. :P

Comment: It's a mock or redis, where Redis has official define `redis.call(cmd, ...)`, if the mock does not follow the official API, then it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question.

When define as `:`, no `self` need.

```
-- hash.lua
function RedisDb:hget(self,k,k2)
    assert((type(k2) == "string")) -- # line 22
    local x = RedisDb.xgetr(self,k,"hash")
    return x[k2]
end
```

change to

```
-- hash.lua
function RedisDb:hget(k,k2)
    assert((type(k2) == "string")) -- # line 22
    local x = RedisDb:xgetr(k,"hash")
    return x[k2]
end
```